# Improve performance of sql query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

I have one huge sql query with below structure using same table due to one to multiple mappings and having 67 occurence of table in sql statement.

SQL structure
: Lets suppose we have table A (columns: B ,C,D,E),

```
select B,
       (select B from A where condition1),
       (select B from A where condition2),
       --and so on(65 more times)
from   table joins
where  cond3;
```

can anyone advice how to deal with performance issue or any programming techniques that I can use .

I tried to add this table where all tables are joined but results are getting impacted due to one to many mappings from this table

Comment: It's really difficult to suggest improvements for such a vague query. However, if you're selecting column(s) from a single row in the same table multiple times but under different conditions, it might be more efficient to use conditional aggregation to get all the information on the rows you need, and then join to that query. E.g. `with a_cols as (select <join columns>, case when condition1 then b end b_cond1, case when condition2 then b end b_cond2, ... from a), select b, a_cols.b_cond1, a_cols.b_cond2, .... from <tables> left outer join a_cols on <join columns>`

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for us to point you to every problem you might have, as you haven't shown us the real query, the execution plan, or any information about table sizes. Performance tuning is a complex exercise that requires putting together multiple pieces of information that isn't easy to communicate in a forum like SO.

However, what you *have* shown is likely to be a problem in many (not all) situations because of this:

```
select B,
       (select B from A where condition1),
       (select B from A where condition2),
       --and so on(65 more times)
from
```

You have 67 separate subqueries nested in the `SELECT` clause of the main block. There's a couple issues with this:

1. Historically the optimizer had to execute these for each row in the parent block, meaning it forced `nested loops` join. That requires careful indexing and even if properly indexed if the # of rows in the main block are excessive, the overhead of all the single block reads for those subqueries builds up and becomes a bottleneck. Recent versions of Oracle have begun being able to rewrite this bad query pattern and turn them into normal joins so a `hash` join can be used instead. But that doesn't always happen and is very hard to control when written in this way. Moral of the story: be very sparing with inline selects inside the `SELECT` clause. A normal join in the `FROM` clause is almost always a better pattern.
2. 67 of them?? That's an excessive # of tables for *any* join pattern. No SQL query should involve that many tables. If I could guess, I'll bet you aren't hitting 67 different tables, but are hitting the same table over and over again, getting a different column each time. If that's the case, then let's rewrite it:

   2a. If you aren't using aggregations (the join key is unique on this other table), simply join normally:

   ```
   SELECT a.col1,
          a.col2,
          b.col1,
          b.col2,
          b.col3, etc..
     FROM tableA a
          LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB on a.fkid = b.pkid
   ```

   2b. If however you *are* doing aggregations, either pre-aggregate and hash join, or use `OUTER APPLY` if you want a nested loops operation:

   ```
   SELECT a.col1,
          a.col2,
          b.col1,
          b.col2,
          b.col3, etc..
     FROM tableA a
          LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT pkid,
                                  MAX(col1) col1,
                                  MAX(col2) col2,
                                  SUM(col3) col3
                             FROM tableB
                            GROUP BY pkid) b on a.fkid = b.pkid
   ```

   Or

   ```
   SELECT a.col1,
          a.col2,
          bx.col1,
          bx.col2,
          bx.col3, etc..
     FROM tableA a
          OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(col1) col1,
                              MAX(col2) col2,
                              SUM(col3) col3
                         FROM tableB b
                        WHERE b.pkid = a.fkid) bx
   ```

The advantage to this last pattern is it lets you do a nested loops operation (useful if you are only pulling a tiny percentage of `tableA` rows) while pulling back multiple aggregate columns instead of just one. That way you only have to hit the table once instead of 67 times.

Again, there are many other things that could be wrong with your query, but this is something to look into based on what you have shared with us.